# How to change database dynamically in Django?

Tags: python, database, django

Is it possible to change active database dynamically in Django?
 For example, use one DB for inserts and updates and switch to other for readonly operations.

Comment: You have multiple database connections in your settings.  Have you read this?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 8):

This is possible by configuring multiple databases in your settings and then using a router to specify which database configuration should be used for read and write.

Go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers and look for "MasterSlaveRouter", which has example code for exactly what you are requesting.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to manually select databases in queries and saves as explain in the [Django Docs on multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/)

Essentially one uses the "using" keyword argument, as in

```
obj.save(using='alias')
```

and the "using" method of the QuerySet like this:

```
Model.objects.using('alias').all()
```

`alias` is the name given to the database in the DATABASES item of the settings.